# Rails Omniauth for Linkedin not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, omniauth-linkedin

I'm trying to get the **Linkedin access token by Omniauth**, using Devise, Omniauth and [omniauth-linkedin-oauth-2](https://github.com/decioferreira/omniauth-linkedin-oauth2). Either with facebook and twitter, I can get the access token, but when I try it with linkedin, I'm **getting the following error** in the omniauth callback:

```
ERROR -- omniauth: (linkedin) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, invalid_request: missing required parameters, includes an invalid parameter value, parameter more than once. : Unable to retrieve access token : appId or redirect uri does not match authorization code or authorization code expired
{"error_description":"missing required parameters, includes an invalid parameter value, parameter more than once. : Unable to retrieve access token : appId or redirect uri does not match authorization code or authorization code expired","error":"invalid_request"}
```

The linkedin app id and secret authentication is working, as I'm getting the callback on omniauth, the thing is I can't realise what the problem is here.

Devise config below:

```
  config.omniauth :linkedin, ENV['LINKEDIN_APP_ID'], ENV['LINKEDIN_APP_SECRET']
```

Any ideas on what could be happening?

Comment: Are you trying this in development or production? In my experience you need to have two Linkedin apps - one that has the exact localhost:portnumber for development and another for production use.

Comment: In development. I have `http://localhost:3000/users/auth/linkedin/callback` in the Authorized Redirect URLs of the Linkedin app

Comment: I had trouble with that - have a look at the docs. I think it was something about it being comma-separated versus linebreak-separated.

Comment: Just looked and it's comma-separated, but the UI makes you think you should put each one on a separate line. Is that it?

Comment: @stef I updated the question with comma-separated, I tried it, and I'm getting the same failure message :(

Comment: I had tons of trouble with attending.io on this. Are you using `omniauth-linkedin-oauth2`? Looking at my code I had to do this: `config.omniauth :linkedin, ENV["LINKEDIN_KEY"], ENV["LINKEDIN_SECRET"], :scope => 'r_basicprofile r_emailaddress', :fields => ['id', 'email-address', 'first-name', 'last-name', 'headline', 'industry', 'picture-url', 'public-profile-url']`

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. Yes, I'm using `omniauth-linkedin-oauth2` and I tried with your config line and still no luck...

Comment: try puts-ing your config just to make sure it really is set?

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem and I found a way to resolve that.
In your Gemfile put this:

```
#Contains a generic OAuth2 strategy for OmniAuth
gem 'omniauth-oauth2', '~> 1.3.1'
```

And finally do:

```
bundle update
```

I think it should work.

More info in:
https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-oauth2/issues/81